# Hive on Spark > Yarn mode > spark configuration > what value to give to spark.master

Tags: configuration, apache-spark, hive

I am trying to HiveQL with my own custom serde (It worked properly with pure Hive). I followed the instruction in: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started

But I am very confused about the part: Start Spark cluster (both standalone and Spark on YARN are supported).
According to my understanding, we only need to Start Spark cluster if Spark is running in standalone mode. But I intend to run Spark on Yarn, is there need to start Spark cluster? What I did is: I just started Hadoop Yarn, and as I really do not know what to set to property spark.master, I just did not set it at all. Probably because of this setting, I got error message when running a Hive query, which uses my own Serde:

```
2015-10-05 20:42:07,184 INFO  [main]: status.SparkJobMonitor (RemoteSparkJobMonitor.java:startMonitor(67)) - Job hasn't been submitted after 61s. Aborting it.

2015-10-05 20:42:07,184 ERROR [main]: status.SparkJobMonitor (SessionState.java:printError(960)) - Status: SENT
2015-10-05 20:42:07,184 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogEnd(148)) - </PERFLOG method=SparkRunJob start=1444066866174 end=1444066927184 duration=61010 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.status.SparkJobMonitor>
2015-10-05 20:42:07,300 ERROR [main]: ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printError(960)) - FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask
2015-10-05 20:42:07,300 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogEnd(148)) - </PERFLOG method=Driver.execute start=1444066848958 end=1444066927300 duration=78342 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
```

...

at the end there is also the following exception:

```
2015-10-05 20:42:16,658 INFO  [stderr-redir-1]: client.SparkClientImpl (SparkClientImpl.java:run(569)) - 15/10/05 20:42:16 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1444066615793_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
2015-10-05 20:42:17,337 WARN  [main]: client.SparkClientImpl (SparkClientImpl.java:stop(154)) - Timed out shutting down remote driver, interrupting...
2015-10-05 20:42:17,337 WARN  [Driver]: client.SparkClientImpl (SparkClientImpl.java:run(430)) - Waiting thread interrupted, killing child process.
2015-10-05 20:42:17,345 WARN  [stderr-redir-1]: client.SparkClientImpl (SparkClientImpl.java:run(572)) - Error in redirector thread.
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at     java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:162)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:272)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.SparkClientImpl$Redirector.run(SparkClientImpl.java:568)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-10-05 20:42:17,371 INFO  [Thread-15]: session.SparkSessionManagerImpl (SparkSessionManagerImpl.java:shutdown(146)) - Closing the session manager.
```

Answer (score 2):

Please, try `set spark.master=yarn-client;`

Comment: I know this is an old discussion, but just in case other people have similar problem in Hive 2.3.4 'yarn-client' is deprecated, so please use spark.master=yarn instead

Answer (score 2):

As from the official documentation [Spark on YARN](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html), you master will be basically:

- **yarn-cluster**: if you're submitting jobs to spark OR
- **yarn-client**: if you want to instantiate SparkContext locally

Don't forget to have the configurarion files (core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml, yarn-site.xml, mapred-site.xml, hive-site.xml, etc) available in the `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` and `YARN_CONF_DIR`. You can set these variables at `<spark_home>/conf/spark-env.sh`